# Route method call based on type parameter without reflection

Tags: c#, generics, types, arraylist

I have a static method ConvertObject<T>(object obj) that converts object-based collections into generic collections. Based on the type of the obj parameter and the type parameter T, the method should return a specific type of collection. For instance, the call ConvertObject<List<string>>(obj), where obj is an ArrayList, would convert the ArrayList into a List<string>.

The problem is that method overloading cannot be used to distinguish between different T parameters, and the same object type (for instance ArrayList) could be converted to different output types based on different type parameters, so I cannot use regular method overloading either.

The best I've come up with is this, which calls ConvertToList<string>(ArrayList a) and returns a List<string>:

```
if (typeof(T).IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List&lt;>))
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Serialization).GetMethod("ConvertToList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T).GetGenericArguments());

    return (T)generic.Invoke(null, new[]{(ArrayList)obj});
}
```

It works perfectly, however I am not comfortable with using reflection. I've seen using Performance Analysis that Type.GetMethod() and MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod() take up a fair amount of CPU time, and also I would like to catch any misusages (such as calling with an array type parameter instead of a List<>) at compile-time, rather than on runtime.

Is there any way to do this using generics and static types, instead of runtime reflection type handling?

Please let me know if the problem description is confusing :)

Comment: What kinds of input and return types are expected? Can't you avoid using non-generic types at the source where they come from?

Comment: The input comes from a JSON deserializing library that deserializees JSON lists and objects into ArrayLists and Hashtables. I could use another library that deserializes directly to generic types, but I haven't been able to find one that isn't very slow when deserializing large amounts of data. So I've build these methods as wrappers for the Hashtable/ArrayList library which is the fastest I've found so far. So unfortunately, I can't avoid using non-generic types at the source.